# Meaning of running out into the road

Tags: adverbs

My dog is very silly ; he is always **running out into** the road.
 What does **running out into** mean?

Answer (score 2):

"*Running out into the road*" essentially means the same as simply "*running into the road*".

Although a road is a surface and you may be more familiar with the concept of someone or something being *on* a road, the road is also an area with defined boundaries, and so when something is *within those boundaries* it is spoken of as being *in* that area. For example, you might say "*stand **inside** the circle*" because a circle is a line or perimeter, but if it were a solid shape marked on the floor you would say "*stand **on** the spot*". "Running into the road" therefore means that the dog has run into the road area and is on the road surface.

The inclusion of the word "into" is partly idiomatic, but also implies *direction*. "Out" or "outwards" can be used to show that something extends *away* from a starting point. In your example, it adds some drama to the situation by describing how the dog is running *away* from something, possibly its owner.

Answer (score 2):

"Running out" has multiple meanings in English - but here it simply means, running from some small area (the sidewalk/pavement, or perhaps from a house or garden) into a more open area (in this case, the road). "Into", of course, is just where the dog runs to. "Into", rather than "to" again implies some defined area, rather than a specific point or place. You might say "John ran out of the house", or "John ran out to the shops" or "John ran out into the fields". "Running out into the road" is a very common fear for the safety of children and pets in busy towns and is an everyday expression.